# Visual Studio 2015 RC SP324099

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Alright so just one day VS2015 RC Stopped working.

The problem is that I have to sign in but signing in doesn't work. I have to update my license but the only way to do it is to sign in.

When I try to sign in I get this error:

> SP324099: Could not complete the operation.

I have tried reinstalling.

I have tried resetting user settings with `devenv.exe /resetsettings`.

I have tried renaming `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7DEBUG` to something else. I changed it to `VS7DEBUG1`.

None of these helped.

I have searched far and wide for ways to solve this problem but I find nothing, can someone please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Updating my [Internet Explorer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie) from version 8 to 11 solved this Visual Studio issue for me. Note that you need to restart your computer before it actually takes effect.

Comment: My work still has IE8 so it might be the issue... Will have to wait I guess.

Comment: Can confirm this was the issue. Try your IT support for an exception.

Comment: I had IE8, so I tried updating to IE11. This failed however. Installed all Windows updates; failed again. 
Eventually I found out VS2015 needs IE10 only. So I tried updating to IE10. Thankfully, that worked :).

Comment: I have IE11 and still experiencing this error. Ridiculous.

Comment: me too I have IE11 and still have this error, are there any way to fix this.

Answer (score 8):

Also very late to the party, but I just encountered this issue on VS2015 Community after reinstalling Windows, and managed to fix it without upgrading IE. On the right of the window where it shows the trial status there's an option to 'Check for updated licences', clicking on this and entering login information worked where the regular sign in window failed.

Comment: This worked for me - thx! IE is version 8.0.760.17514 and VSC2015 tries to redirect to https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf -- entering the login information re-enabled the license.

Answer (score 3):

Turning back your system date for few days sort out my problem.

I know, It is just temporary solution to move on the things, otherwise you have to keep updated your license, Windows and Visual Studio 2015 to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this issue with VS2015 Community on Windows 10. Due to the fact I was dual-booting linux, the system clock was set to UTC. Changing the clock back to local time made the problem go away.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, where I was assigned a laptop at my job and it had a 30 day evaluation version that was expired. When I tired to sign in with my Microsoft account which is also for my MSDN subscription, I get this same error message.

SIGN IN failed
CHECK FOR LICENSE failed also

However, using my MSDN subscription, I was able to obtain a product key, and applied that to Visual Studio, it fixed the error without having to sign in.

Answer (score 1):

I installed Internet Explorer 11 to make this work. I had removed IE in control panel and used Chrome only.

Answer (score 0):

Installing IE10 fixed this problem for me.
http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/A/C/8AC7C482-BC74-492E-B978-7ED04900CEDE/IE10-Windows6.1-x86-en-us.exe -Internet Explorer 10 (32-bit)
http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/E/0/CE0AB8AE-E6B7-43F7-9290-F8EB0EA54FB5/IE10-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe - Internet Explorer 10 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but you should probably upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 RTM (Community Edition). It's free and probably fixes a few bugs in the process.

Answer (score -3):

```
@echo off
set _date=%DATE:/=-%
DATE DD/MM/YYYY
start devenv.exe
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 >NUL
DATE %_date%
```

Change **DD/MM/YYYY** to date of install!