# Visual studio 2015 Enterprise Sign In Error: SP324099

Tags: outlook, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to sign in with **microsoft visual studio 2015 Enterprise edition** with my microsoft account.

**Error:**

> SP324099: Could not complete the operation.

My microsoft account is working fine in browser. I have seen already question posted :[Visual Studio 2015 RC SP324099](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31419539/visual-studio-2015-rc-sp324099)

But Could not find appropriate solution as I have updated `Internet Explorer` browser with latest version. Still m unable to continue by signing in with `VS2015`.

Answer (score 1):

I was gettting this error to with the IE8 as it tries to redirect to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf`.  I did **NOT upgrade* to a later version of IE *instead* I clicked on `Check for updated licences`, re-entered my Live account credentials and was good to go.

Have you tried `Add an account...` ?

Have you exhausted all the options mentioned in [How to Unlock Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn950037.aspx)?